# What is "${env.M2_HOME}" and how do I set it?

Tags: maven

I'm getting this error when trying to do a maven build:

```
[INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\[[project]]\build.xml:17:
 settingsFile does not exist: C:\[[project]]\${env.M2_HOME}\conf\settings.xml
```

Is this the same as M2.HOME? How do I set it when I don't have access to environment variables due to silly IT security policies in my company? Is it possible to set it within the project using IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `M2_HOME` environment variable.

```
export M2_HOME=/path/to/maven
```

Or since you're on Windows (sorry):

```
set M2_HOME=c:/path/to/maven
```

Comment: I like windows though :P